# Fatal error when using update() in $wpdb class

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am trying to update a custom table in my WordPress database, but I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on null in /Users/jlf/project/wp-admin/controls.php on line 21
```

This is my PHP:

```
    ini_set("display_errors",1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $accentColor    = $_POST["accentColor"];
    $donateColor    = $_POST["donateColor"];
    $donateHover    = $_POST["donateHover"];
    $ticketStatus   = $_POST["ticketStatus"];
    $logoPath       = $_POST["logoPath"];
    $characterPath  = $_POST["characterPath"];

    global $wpdb;
    $q_result = $wpdb->update(             // line 21
        'wp_nyicff', 
        array(
            'accent_color'      =>  $accentColor, 
            'donate_color'      =>  $donateColor, 
            'donate_hover'      =>  $donateHover, 
            'tickets_status'    =>  $ticketStatus, 
            'logo_path'         =>  $logoPath, 
            'character_path'     => $characterPath
            ),
        array( 'id' => 1 ), 
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' ), 
        array( '%d' )
    );

    if ($q_result) {
        print('<script>window.location.href = "index.php";</script>');
    }
    else   {
        die(mysql_error());
        print("<br><a href='index.php'>back</a>");
    }
```

All of the variables echo their proper values. I've globalized `$wpdb`. What could be going wrong?

Comment: That's clearly because `$wpdb` is `null` ;) We can't help you more.

Comment: How are you calling that code, via plugin or in the function.php file?

Comment: @EnriqueChavez this file is located in my `wp-admin` directory, but I've set up the widget that submits this form via my `functions.php`.

Comment: @ElonThan but isn't globalizing $wpdb both in this file and the file that generates the form (that submits this data) classifying it?

Comment: You should not put files or code directly in the wp-admin, if you need to add custom code you should use plugins or if a custom theme in the functions.php file. If you are woking with Widgets take a deep read to this https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$wpdb` was null. I thought by globalizing it in this file would have prevented that but I was wrong. Turns out I needed to require the `wp-load.php` file.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpdb-returning-null helped me figure this one out.

At the top of the PHP I wrote:

```
require("../wp-load.php");
```

Also, I've learned that putting files directly into the `/wp-admin` directory is bad practice (as I did in this scenario). It would be better to make a plug-in that handled all of this.